# C++ STL: The third parameter of sort(), why the functor is faster than inline function?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, functor, inline-functions

```
inline bool mycmp(int i, int j) {
    return (i < j);
}

class mycmp2 {
public:
    bool operator()(int i, int j) {
        return (i < j);
    }
};
```

above is my example.
I want know why the functor one is faster than the inline funcion!

```
//test example:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
struct CompareFunctor {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const {
        return a < b;
    }
};

inline bool compareFunction(int a, int b) {
    return a < b;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> nums(10000000);
    std::generate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), std::rand);

    {
        std::vector<int> numsObj = nums;
        clock_t start = clock();
        std::sort(numsObj.begin(), numsObj.end(), CompareFunctor());
        clock_t end = clock();
        double duration = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        std::cout << "use functor：" << duration << " second" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> numsFunc = nums;
        clock_t start = clock();
        std::sort(numsFunc.begin(), numsFunc.end(), compareFunction);
        clock_t end = clock();
        double duration = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        std::cout << "use inline function：" << duration << " second" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Translation: "The above is the code I used for testing, and the result shows that the functor is faster. I would like to know why. It seems that the functor is also an inline function at the underlying level. Is there any optimization performed by the compiler?"

Comment: What is the output of your program?

Comment: What compiler (& settings) did you use to measure the speed?

Comment: https://quick-bench.com/q/JemhAR4I6x772NVEFBqA0NCcYks - better benchmark

Comment: However for gcc it's exactly the same https://quick-bench.com/q/pPvLVGUk7OG7CMXsq7s3AB6L43I

Comment: @pptaszni different for clang... Highly compiler dependant.

Comment: Ironically enough, it's because the free `inline` function can't be inlined. The `inline` qualifier has very little to do with the inline expansion of a function call.

Comment: Can confirm. On my system with gcc and `-O3` and 30 repetitions: functor: `0.837923s ... 0.84363s`. free function: `0.782855s ... 0.792083s`. The gap appears to be consistent.

Comment: Inline function has no sense when passed as a function pointer argument. The result is unchanged If you remove `inline`. GCC can't inline the functor' operator, thus the results are equal. Clang can inline the functor' operator and it's faster.